# Delete rows from a table with not in ( another table )

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I have two tables A and B, in the B there is a foreign key from A, what I want to do is to delete all the rows from A that they don't have an occurrence in B, I execute the following query but it's not working :

```
DELETE from A 
WHERE  id_A
       not in (select DISTINCT(foreign_key_of_A_in_B) from B)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Try `select * from A where id_A
       not in (select ...`. Do you get any rows?

Comment: Show us the table definitions. (I want to know the fk definition.)

Comment: Please answer Jarlh questions in order for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for the help, Gordon's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My first recommendation is to try `not exists` rather than `not in`:

```
DELETE a FROM a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE b.foreign_key_of_A_in_B = a.id_A);
```

`NOT IN` returns false or `NULL` if *any* value in the subquery is `NULL`.  That is how the operator is defined.  `NOT EXISTS` has more expected behavior.  So, if you have any `NULL` values in the subquery, this will work (i.e. delete rows) but the `NOT IN` version will not.

I would recommend that you try the logic out using `SELECT` before doing a `DELETE`:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE b.foreign_key_of_A_in_B = A.id_A);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon for the solution and the explanation (didn't know this behavior with null values about not exists before), it works like a charm !

Answer (score 4):

A standard for DELETE FROM table WHERE id NOT IN would look like this:

```
DELETE from Table_A 
WHERE  id -- ID of Table_A
       not in (select ID FROM Table_B)
```

This should find the IDs not in Table A from Table B, as your question states

Try this in a SELECT statement first to see if it returns the correct rows:

```
SELECT * from Table_A
WHERE  id -- ID of Table_A
       not in (select ID FROM Table_B)
```

Don't forget to cross-reference some rows to double check.

Comment: That's what I've done, but in this case using not exists as Gordon's explained is the best way.